# Why are Spanish "casa rurales" priced per person?

Tags: accommodation, spain

When searching for a *Casa Rural* in Spain, I've noticed most properties are priced per person. That seems odd, because guests do not share the properties with others. For example, consider [this property near Salamanca](https://www.escapadarural.com/casa-rural/salamanca/c-t-r--la-estacion), marketed at €15/person/night. It's large enough for 12 people. What is the rationale to rent it out per *person* per night? Can I really rent it with 2 people for €30/night?

Comment: Sometimes you pay for beds, sometimes for rooms, and sometimes for entire houses. It depends on the casa IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

Hah-hah. No. There's a reason why the price includes "approx." I clicked the ? and got these statements:

> El precio medio es un indicativo para que el viajero pueda hacerse una
>   idea del precio aproximado del alojamiento y pueda compararlo con
>   otros.
>
> Este precio se calcula haciendo una media con los precios por noche de
>   todas sus opciones de alquiler, durante los siguientes 6 meses.
>
> No se contemplan en el cálculo las ofertas especiales, ni descuentos
>   por número de noches o personas.
>
> Para saber precios más exactos sobre el alojamiento, introduce tus
>   fechas y plazas en el buscador.

Google Translate gives:

> The average price is indicative so that the traveler can get an idea
>   of the approximate price of the accommodation and can compare it with
>   others.
>
> This price is calculated by making an average with the prices per
>   night of all your rental options, during the following 6 months.
>
> Special offers, discounts for number of nights or people are not
>   included in the calculation.
>
> To know more exact prices about the accommodation, enter your dates
>   and places in the search engine.

The 15€ per person per night is if you have 12 people and calculate the cost per person. In the statement they say that the value is using six months of rates of all your options so you can better compare properties. That's pretty misleading if they're dividing the nightly rates by the maximum number of people who can stay.

The actual nightly rate appears to be 180€, which I found when I tried 2 people, 2 nights for a weekend in March. That works out to 15€ per person per night if you have 12 people staying.

Comment: _"That's pretty misleading"_ Not really. A 5-room _casa rural_ is not intended for just 2 people, but for families or groups that actually need 5 rooms. They are comparing "price of booking 12 people here" vs "price of booking 12 people in a hotel / camping / etc.". Saying that it is misleading is like saying that bus fares are misleading because renting the whole bus is much more expensive. If you only need room for 2, you probably should be booking just a room, not a full building.

Comment: @walen Hotels don't charge per person, they charge per room. So that is really no reason or justification for this way of pricing.

Comment: @RHA Uhhh no, they charge per person and room. Double rooms for a single person are cheaper than double rooms for 2 people. They also charge more if you want to add one supplemental bed for another person in the same room, etc.

Comment: @walen They charge per room and may give a (small) discount for singles (and often they do not). And off course they charge extra for extras, but extra beds are often only allowed for children. Otherwise, book a triple room.

Comment: @RHA are you talking about casas rurales or your experience elsewhere? I've seen both cases.